# Why my PhpStorm does not have needed interface for PHPUnit tests?

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

I'm watching a video about Unit-testing. An author of that video uses very convenient interface of PhpStorm that shows details of testing.

[image]

But I don't have this. I have a simple, not pleasant interface))

[image]

The year of the video is 2015. My version of PhpStorm - 2018.3 (I think it's much newer)

Why should I do to make interface of my PhpStorm like on the first picture? Do I need to install some plugin?

If it helps: I use it with Yii2.

Comment: If you already have PhpStorm installed, then start it as root, then go to `help > check for updates..`

Comment: @СергейО. Show what options you have under the cog icon? I guess it will be one of them. Here is mine (PhpStorm 2021.1.2 on Windows) -- https://i.imgur.com/qZGfZ75.png

Comment: @LazyOne I set it like on your screen, but nothing happend))  https://i.stack.imgur.com/66wGA.png

Comment: @СергейО. TBH -- I do not know. I'm sure that if I would be using it I would be able to click around and sort it out (because I had the same about a year or so ago) ... but right now .. no ideas. Anyway: 1) Try "Restore default layout" button (2nd from the bottom on the left, above the "pin" icon) 2) Maybe the ">" collapse/expand icon is not visible? Try clicking there or use keyboard navigation (e.g. Arrow Rigth or Enter) 3) Try with having all 2 tests passed. 4) What kind of Run/Debug Config that is (the Test scope)? A class? Show a screenshot as well (maybe it matter somehow).

Comment: @СергейО. 5) Try a latest PhpStorm 2021.1.2 version (to see how it behaves there). You can run it in parallel to your current version/ID-wide settings are separate (just not open the same project in both versions at the same time) 6) Another "random" idea -- maybe it depends on PHPUnit version as well ... (but it seems to work fine here even with PHPUnit 4.5.1 here (PHAR version; with PHP 7.4 -- got deprecation warnings but it works))

Comment: @СергейО. Right now the best guess: 1) "Process finished with exit code 1" might be the reason -- IDE sees it as a failed run. 2) Some bug in PhpStorm that is present in your version. Try latest 2021.1.2 to compare...

Comment: @LazyOne I found the answer (I wrote it below). Thank you for help. I am very grateful

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that in

`Settings` > `Languages & Frameworks` > `PHP` > `PHPUnit`

I have chosen the option to use Composer autoload to load PHPUnit. And Path to script I have put `/vendor/bin/phpunit`.

When I set `/vendor/autoload.php` it started work as expected

---

The only problem is I was forced to update *PhpStorm* to 2021. Only when I updated it and click "Run test" it showed me the message

> Test framework quit unexpectedly

I google it and found the answer. Why didn't *PhpStorm 2018*  show me the message - I don't know.